# Get the recent value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

My table is as follows

```
Id InvoiceNo Status    Amt
1  ABC/1     Paid      100
2  ABC/2     Pending   200
3  XYZ       Rejected  100
```

The result I want is as follows

```
Id InvoiceNo  Status      Amt
1  ABC        Pending     300
2  XYZ        Rejected    100
```

Kindly help me to get the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order of the rows is based on what?

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier, Its based on ID

Comment: Still don't understand. Do you want to fetch only the `pending` and `rejected` ones?

Comment: No. Kindly see the InvoiceNo in my desired result table. ABC/1 and ABC/2 should be ABC and their equivalent Amt, must the be the sum of 2 rows.I wanna display the recent status along with ABC.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

Select * from table_name where Status != 'Paid' GROUP BY InvoiceNo

Comment: It is all dynamic... I actually dont maintain a separate table for status.

Comment: But for payment i think there are only there kind of status are there. 1.Pending 2. Paid 3.Done and 4. Rejected